# How to call a function inside class without $this?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I want to hook a form onto an external function. The hook load my form by the name:

```
add_action(media_uploader, 'the_hook');
function the hook(){
//.....
return wp_iframe( 'media_upload_potato_form', $errors );
}
function media_upload_potato_form(){ }// my form
```

If I use the above functions in a class as showing below, it gets error:

```
return wp_iframe($this->media_upload_potato_form, $errors);
```

How can I hook up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
return wp_iframe(array('YourClassName', 'media_upload_potato_form'), $errors);
```

Comment: This should only work it the function is static; array($object, 'method_name') should work for non-static.